# Enable voice control on Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, voice-command

How do I enable voice control in my LGE Nexus 4 for system commands like "turn on bluetooth", etc?

Answer (score 1):

By default that is not possible on stock Android phones.

It works for Samsung, because they have basically taken the Android source code and made their own fork of the repo. Having access to the source code allows them to turn on/off or even edit features.

Comment: thats also why it takes so long to get an update to the OS whenever a new version comes out.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Google Now, don't you ? For this, you have to click on the microphone of a Google Search bar. You can do this with the one of the home screen. You can also open the Google Search app and doing this with its search bar too. For opening Google Search, do a long press on the Home button and then swipe to the circle with the Google logo. Google Now will be opened. You can also use the app shortcut (in the Launcher or anywhere else).

Comment: I know but Google now Voice search does not support changing system settings like turn on/off bluetooth or WIFI. But things are possible in Samsung phones using S Voice apps.